# Conditional row style xsl and avoiding duplicate code

Tags: css, xslt, html-table, xslt-1.0

I need to show all rows which are over 2 years old from today in bold.
How do I do it without duplicating code?
I can figure out the condition, but can't figure out how not to duplicate all the code with a different style for bold.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="albums-by-country" match="Album" use="Country" />
<xsl:template match="Albums">
 <html>
 <head>
<style>
h4 { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;

}
</style>
</head>
  <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Album[count(. | key('albums-by-country', Country)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="Country" />
        <h4 style="color:green;"><xsl:value-of select="Country" style="color:red;" /><br /></h4>


                  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#979994">
      <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Link</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Company</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('albums-by-country', Country)"> 
<xsl:sort select="Date" />
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Link"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Company"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>

  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(Date)>4">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(Date,5,2),'/',substring(Date,7,8),'/',substring(Date,1,4))"/></td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="concat('01/01/',substring(Date,1,4))"/></td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
      <td style="color:red;"><xsl:value-of select="Artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
      <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Total Amount</td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffff00"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('albums-by-country', Country)/Price)"/></td>
            </tr>
  </table>
   <html>
  <body>
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are bolding by adding style to tr or td's.  Just use the attribute function within the if conditional.

```
 <tr>  <!-- or td -->
    <xsl:if test="{Older the 2 years}">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">bold whatever</attribute>
    </if>
```